# loading image from a project's folder (not bin) in java

Tags: java, import, path, embedded-resource

I imported some images into my project `javaproject` under the folder name `images`. Now, since earlier the paths were referring to C: drive, I figured I've to change the path. I tried using

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("images\\img1.jpg");
```

I'm not sure what happened there. There was no error yielded whatsoever, but the image is not displaying. I'm fairly new to programming in general so I can't think alternate methods.

How do I re-direct it to the main directory of my project and into my `images` folder? 
Also, I cant have a strict location like:

c:/users/me/java/etc because if this JAR is ever on different computer it won't work.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `"images\\img1.jpg"` Don't use backslash in paths for `getResource..`, it always must be `/`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the above approach then all resources files have to be stored under `src/main/resources`